# How to sanitize allocated memory in C before using free function?

Tags: c, memory, free, sanitization

I have created a nested struct called employee. I allocate a space for an employee from heap using **malloc**. Then, I release the space using **free**. As far as I know, **free** function only marks a location available for the future allocation. Hence, the content of allocated memory remains in the memory and it causes heap inspection.

Structs I defined in the beginning of my program as follow.

```c
struct address{
    char *city;
    int zip;
}

struct employee{
    char *name;
    struct address add;
}
```

I implemented a function called sanitize to replace the private fields with junk values (`0xAA` in this case). Then, I tested **sanitize** in the main function.

```c
void sanitize(char *ptr, int size){
    memset(ptr, 0xAA, size);
}

int main()
{
    struct employee* emp;
    emp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 40);
    emp->name = "John";
    emp->add.city = "London";
    emp->add.zip = 221;
    printf("%s\n", emp->add.city);
    sanitize(&(emp->add), sizeof(struct address));
    printf("%s\n", emp->add.city);
    return 0;
}
```

During runtime I get segmentation fault. What is wrong with my program? How and in which order shoul I **sanitize** nested structs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to test, what happens if you memset with 0 instead of 0xAA?

Comment: You overwrite a pointer with `0xaaaaaaaa` and then you dereference it. What do you expect?

Comment: Modern compilers commonly know that `free` releases memory and that any changes to memory immediately before `free` do not have any *observable behavior* as defined by the C standard. This means the compiler may eliminate any `memset` or similar code before a `free`, so the memory will not be cleared.

Comment: What is the threat you are seeking to reduce by sanitizing memory? General-purpose multiuser operating systems ensure the contents of memory in your process are not made visible to other processes, except when sharing is explicitly requested. This includes clearing memory before it is reallocated to other processes. So sanitizing memory only protects it from other things within your own process (which you need to trust anyway) or exceptional attacks that can discover memory contents in spite of operating system protections…

Comment: … The latter do occur (as in [Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)) and [Meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability)), but knowing the threat is important for deciding how to mitigate it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to properly allocate memory for your objects. Functions to do it help a lot.

```
struct employee *new_employee()
{
  struct employee *emp = (struct employee*)malloc( sizeof(struct employee) );
  if (emp)
  {
    emp->name = NULL;
    emp->add.city = NULL;
  }
  return emp;
}
```

Likewise, create a function to destroy an employee:

```
struct employee *destroy_employee( struct employee *emp )
{
  if (emp)
  {
    if (emp->name)     free( emp->name );
    if (emp->add.city) free( emp->add.city );
    free( emp );
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Likewise your sanitize function needs to know about employees:

```
void sanitize_employee( struct employee *emp )
{
  if (emp)
  {
    if (emp->name)     memset( emp->name,     0xAA, strlen( emp->name     ) );
    if (emp->add.city) memset( emp->add.city, 0xAA, strlen( emp->add.city ) );
    emp->add.zip = 0xAAAAAAAA;
  }
}
```

Now you can easily create and destroy employees:

```
struct employee *emp = new_employee();
emp->name = strdup( "John" );
emp->add.city = strdup( "London" );
emp->add.zip = 221;

...

sanitize_employee( emp );
emp = destroy_employee( emp );
```

Notice how we take care to always allocate space for every object, and delete each object appropriately. You could very well combine the sanitize and destroy functions.

There is an important concern to your structure design. If you *change* an employee’s details (for example, changing his name) it is possible that your sanitization can fail and employee data can be left unsanitized. For this you should make it a strict policy to never mutate an employee structure: make it const, or make additional functions to mutate the data and perform proper sanitization and memory management (sanitize, free the old value, `strdup` the new value).

You might simply want to create a fixed-size record to handle employee data. This would simplify your life significantly and free you from having to deal with quite as many memory-managing employee functions.

Comment: When I try to sanitize, I get Access violation writing location error. Why is that?

Comment: Jabberwocky answered that in the comment to your question.

Comment: You need to be careful using `memset()` to sanitize memory. Any compiler is free to elide the call to `memset()` under the as-if rule because a call to `memset()` immediately before calling `free()`  has no observable effects from the perspective of defined behavior of your program. Clearing the memory yourself is subject to the same treatment. You can create a `sanitize()` function that uses `memset()`, put it in a separate file, and compile that file with zero optimizations. Also, if you have `memset_s()`, that is not subject to being removed (about the only Annex K positive feature...)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It is safe to compile the separate file with optimizations, as long as it contains nothing that would let the compiler know the memory is about to be freed and the linker is not doing link-time optimization that would affect this.

Comment: What if I change employee struct with adress pointer like struct employee {
    char *name;
    struct address *add;
}? What should I do in this case?